# Postgres single query for function and temp table it generates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wonder if in Postgres there is any way to replace below 2-queries call by single query:

```sql
SELECT my_func(8,CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT * FROM tmp_table_generated_by_my_func
```

my_func is generating temp table want then use for other queries

I tried below but doesn't work (compiler seems doesn't recognise tmp table)

```sql
    WITH 
    x AS(
        SELECT * FROM  my_func(8,CURRENT_DATE)
    ), 
    y AS(
        SELECT * FROM tmp_table_generated_by_my_func
    ) 
    SELECT * FROM y
```

Comment: Why not simply make `my_func()` _return_ that table?

Comment: From here [SELECT WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): "The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. ..." . So best bet is the `y` is not seeing the table generated by `x`. Use @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion and use return  [table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-overview.html#PLPGSQL-ARGS-RESULTS) *43.1.2. Supported Argument and Result Data Types* or [query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) *43.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY*

Comment: Reason I'm returning table is this particular function returns 10 different tables depending of parameter given. If I declare it returning table (or out params) only 1 set of column can be returned (AFAIK)

Comment: You have two choices  1) Use the first form you show, the sequential queries. 2) Create a function for each table that returns each table.

Comment: I know both solutions. I wondered  if there is any 3rd